# Validation of registration fields in Keycloak and changes in error messages

Tags: keycloak

I added my "date of birth" field to the registration field. Is it possible to validate in Keycloak so that only users over 18 years old can register or that the date is correct (no more than the current year).
And also how can I change the error messages in the registration form? If I don't fill in a required field, the error message "Please specify this field." is returned, how can I change it?

I tried using a user profile where you could set the registration fields, but there is no setting for an error message when the field is empty.
There is nothing at all to check the date.

[screen reg form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5fPW.png)